# Flutter/Firebase - Select screen - Eye Color multi-select for diff colors - Can't get query based on selection

Tags: flutter, firebase, filtering

I know it's a big ask but this one is killing me. I've worked on it for 10+ hours and no closer to finding the 'darn' issue. The user has a selection screen with several categories accessible by a horizontal scrolling row. Including in the options, and the ONLY option I'm focusing on during debug, is 'EYE-COLOR' with possible selections of all, blue, brown, green, hazel. I can't get the query to selection. What I've tried to do is extensive and nothing has touched it. The firebase collection is named 'people' the data filed is named 'EYE-COLOR' and the value of 3 of the 10 test records is 'BLUE' (caps and lower are accurate).

Whatever option is selected the result is the same with all records being returned. I wll post the code and some screen shots.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

[![selection screenshot][1]][1]

***Debug Console Print Output:***

`enter code here`flutter: Selected eye colors: [BLUE]
`enter code here`flutter: !-Selected criteria: {EYE-COLOR: BLUE}
`enter code here`flutter: ++Received Search Criteria: {EYE-COLOR: BLUE}
`enter code here`flutter: --Received Search Criteria: {}
`enter code here`flutter: <>Constructed query based on search criteria: `enter code here`CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(people)

*** Cant get my damn flutter code to post into this damn box, can't show the damn code ***

Comment: You really need to copy that code in there, otherwise you will definitely not get help and the question will be closed.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots. It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Understand. Deleting account now. Sure it's a great service to others but a bit too 'structured' for me.

Comment: NoSQL is very different from SQL and it takes a different mindset and approach. Once you understand it, you'll find it's incredibly fast and "infinitely" scalable (and multi-user, and online first and has user presence and and and... lots of benefits)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with my code, it was Firebases query limitations. You can't directly query 2 or more fields. I've moved the database to MySQL on a godaddy hosting plan I wasn't using.

Comment: This is not correct. Firestore can definitely be queried on multiple fields. There are several examples in the documentation - it's called a [Compound (AND) Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_and_queries). The example shows querying for a `state = CO AND name = Denver`; state is field 1, name is field 2. Only Range queries are limited to a single field (but there are ways around that!)